# Autodesk Forge/ Platform Services nodeJS app for Simple 3D viewer not showing any 3d models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am following this tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/GTIC11VHZH0?si=b9Jnbbz30TAeHZJL) and implementing the code from [Autodesk tutorials](https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/)  this site to make a simple 3d model viewer using forge. I am also using the Autodesk Platform Servies extension on VSCode (petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools) which enables me to see the buckets in my sidebar. I try to upload a dwg file in my bucket and manually translate it as well by right clicking on it, but it still does not show on my viewer app. I then try to upload a revit file from my local system and it shows error in the console on inspecting:

```
main.js:94 Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading &#39;status&#39;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at getManifest (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Model Viewer 3d\services\forge\md.js:22:26)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at async C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Model Viewer 3d\routes\models.js:22:26</pre>
</body>
</html>

    at onModelSelected (main.js:73:19)
```

and this is the error in my node terminal :

```
Server listening on port 8080...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at getManifest (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Model Viewer 3d\services\forge\md.js:22:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)  
    at async C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Model Viewer 3d\routes\models.js:22:26
```

I tried making changes to the Initializer function and add env:AutodeskProduction but to no avail.
I dont understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would prove to be beneficial. Thank You